# Switching between Visual Studio windows/tabs web browser style

Tags: visual-studio-2008, user-interface, ide, mdichild

So,  I'm not completely sure this is the best idea ever but I do find myself trying to switch tabs in VS 2010 using [CTRL] + [1, etc] to switch windows (tabs). Is it possible to configure VS to behave like a web browser causing CTRL+1 switch to the first open window?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef...) has very similar funcionality:

> Tab Behavior More Commands for Navigation (New!)
>   ...
>   Activate a specific pinned tab by Ctrl+Num Pad 1 through 0
>   Activate a specific regular tab by Ctrl+Alt+Num Pad 1 through 0
>   ...

Amongst other nice features, read more below:

- http://10rem.net/blog/2010/07/26/visual-studio-productivity-power-tools-walkthrough
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/09/visual-studio-2010-productivity-power-tool-extensions.aspx

Answer (score 20):

you can use `ctrl + tab` to switch between VS2010 windows (tabs).

Comment: Yeah, that one I know. I'd like to add the ability to change windows using ctrl + number.